# A while loop that my teacher instructed not to edit returns the value of my for loop, but is making it run twice

Tags: java

My teacher has assigned me to create a code with the given methods getScrabbleScore and scrabbleLetterValue. Everything in the code has been pre written, I was just requested to fill in getScrabbleScore. When debugging through IntelliJ, it showed that the output would be correct if it weren't for the condition of the while loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * @author your_name
 */

/*You ONLY need to change the body of getScrabbleScore under the "TODO" comment. DO NOT change anything else.*/

public class WordScore {

    int scrabbleScore;
    String word;

    /**
     * @param word int to record scrabble word
     */
    WordScore(String word) {
        this.word = word.toLowerCase();
        this.scrabbleScore = getScrabbleScore();
    }

    /**
     * @param tile char to return value for
     * @return point value for specific tile
     */
    public int scrabbleLetterValue(char tile) {
        switch (tile) {
            case 'a':
            case 'e':
            case 'i':
            case 'l':
            case 'n':
            case 'o':
            case 'r':
            case 's':
            case 't':
            case 'u':
                return 1;
            case 'd':
            case 'g':
                return 2;
            case 'b':
            case 'c':
            case 'm':
            case 'p':
                return 3;
            case 'f':
            case 'h':
            case 'v':
            case 'w':
            case 'y':
                return 4;
            case 'k':
                return 5;
            case 'j':
            case 'x':
                return 8;
            case 'q':
            case 'z':
                return 10;
            default:
                return -1;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return int word score value as described in project instructions
     */
    public int getScrabbleScore() {
        /** TODO: Defnition for getScrabbleScore
         */
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            scrabbleScore += scrabbleLetterValue(word.charAt(i));
        }
        return scrabbleScore;


    }

    /* DO NOT edit this main method. If you do, you can reset your assignment to restore the method.*/

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        WordScore ws;
        while (read.hasNextLine()) {
            ws = new WordScore(read.nextLine());
            System.out.println(ws.getScrabbleScore());
        }
    }
}
```

My desired input for example with "javelin" would be 17, however I get 34.

Comment: You should probably reset `scrabbleScore` to 0 before each call to the method `getScrabbleScore()`.

Comment: `System.out.println(ws.getScrabbleScore());` should be `System.out.println(ws.scrabbleScore);`.  You're calling getScrabbleScore() twice.

Comment: You call getScrabbleScore twice: one in the constructor, another one in the System.out.println(). Each time the value is computed again without resetting.

Answer (score 3):

The general problem is that the code is badly structured - not from you but from your teacher.

The method `getScrabbleScore` should either be private and called **once** or
The method should be public **but** not change the state of the `WordScore` instance by not using a field `scrabbleScore`.

Now you have two options, depending on which way you think is more correct.

***Option 1***: write `scrabbleScore = 0` as the first statement in `getScrabbleScore`, resetting the field every time you need to calculate.
***Option 2***: Add a line `int score = 0` in your method and `return score` at the end, leaving the *field* `scrabbleScore` untouched.

There is no absolutely correct answer here since the code is flawed to begin with.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't like the structure at all. It's so overcomplicated. But declaring it as 0 worked like a charm. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Since the condition in the `while` loop is using the `getScrabbleScore()` method, you should not be doing that on initializing the `ws` object. The duplication is caused by running the method once on initialization and once in response to the user's input; since the method simply increments the current value of the field.

Removing this line from the constructor should solve the problem:

```
this.scrabbleScore = getScrabbleScore();
```

If the constructor is part of the instructor's provided code, I agree that it's not optimal, but the suggestion in the comments of resetting `scrabbleScore` to 0 at the beginning of the `getScrabbleScore` method may be the cleanest workaround. You'd still be doing the work twice, but if you're not allowed to remove the source of the duplication, this will make it work.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `scrabbleScore` is visible to all methods in your class. Your method `getScrabbleScore()` adds the values of the word to `scrabbleScore` correctly from what I can tell, however `scrabbleScore` is not reset between subsequent calls. You can easily fix this by setting `scrabbleScore` to 0 before you begin your for loop:

```
scrabbleScore = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
{
    scrabbleScore += scrabbleLetterValue(word.charAt(i));
}
return scrabbleScore;
```

OR, use a separate, local variable and return that.

```
int localScore = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
{
    localScore += scrabbleLetterValue(word.charAt(i));
}
return localScore;
```